# How to use the private key and pass phrase in pgp encryption file in node js?

Tags: node.js, encryption, pgp

I need to decrypt an xml file with this `pgp` encryption method in node js, when i use my key it says `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'readArmored' of undefined`.

My code is :

```
const openpgp = require("openpgp");
const fs = require("fs");
const privateKeyArmored = `-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: OpenPGP v2.0.8
Comment: https://sela.io/pgp/
shgfdjksagfajkfgsjksgjksgfjks
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----`;
const passphrase = `Verticurl@EsteeLauder`;

openpgp.config.allow_unauthenticated_stream = true;

decrypt();
async function decrypt() {
  const privateKey = (await openpgp.key.readArmored([privateKeyArmored])).keys[0];
  await privateKey.decrypt(passphrase);

  const decrypted = await openpgp.decrypt({
    message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(fs.createReadStream("ConsumerBestRecordList_MDM_20210303_01_21_21_278.xml")),
    privateKeys: [privateKey],
  });

  let readStream = decrypted.data;
  let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("decrypted-dataset.xml", { flags: "a" });
  readStream.pipe(writeStream);
  readStream.on("end", () => console.log("done!"));
}
```

How to rectify this error and give correct form of key and pass phrase.

Comment: You are assuming all of your promises will succeed but when they do not there is not `catch` and so they bubble up to the process.

Comment: @Todd Can you be more precise I cannot understand it

Comment: I was referring to trapping the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` which I see now isn't necessarily helpful. [openpgp docs](https://openpgpjs.org/openpgpjs/)  scroll down to "Encrypt and decrypt String data with PGP keys" I think shows what you want.